# Bootstrap V5 SassError: Undefined mixin : while move up from @import to @use module system

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins, bootstrap-5

I'm moving up to new **SASS module system** from **@import** to **@use** but I have some issues while I do that with **bootstrap v5** :

[image]

**from :**

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

**to :**

```
@use "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@use "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@use "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@use "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

Answer (score 1):

The new sass ruel `@use` works complete different from the old rule `@import`. With `@use` you have to import i.e. your variables to every file where you need them. So to replace the new rule against the new one does not work. I fyou want to work with `@use` you need a complete new project structure.

For more information have a look to this question:
[When importing a file with @use then: Error Undefined Mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66365150/when-importing-a-file-with-use-then-error-undefined-mixin/66366316#66366316)

As Bootstrap is a close module wich is working internal with `@import` there is a special way to get the whole framework at once. Here is an example, - but I didn't test this special solution right now:
[How to import and customize bootstrap with @use in SASS/SCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66499246/how-to-import-and-customize-bootstrap-with-use-in-sass-scss/66499247#66499247)